# can i make a panel transparent for a certain key color like the forms c#?

Tags: c#

i have a panel and i wanna make it transparent for a color key (black) and place a flash in it with black background color, then i can still show the form under it

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can do panel-level (i.e. not form-level) transparency in WPF.

In WinForms you can't (only forms have the `TransparencyKey` and `Opacity` properties).  A quick hack would be to create a completely borderless form with `TransparencyKey` set to `Black`, play the Flash movie on this form and then float the form over top of your main form.

Comment: +1, Yup.  Same restriction in WPF btw, control transparency isn't going to work on the flash.  The additional requirement for WPF is that the Window also has to be borderless.